# pantalla se oscurece al darle click a enlace del menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, id

Tengo una pagina estilo one page al que le agregue un código JS para que al darle click al enlace, el menu se cierre (estando de 768px o menos o sea móvil) pero hace que al estar el sitio en tamaño de escritorio se oscurezca al darle click a cualquier link.

No se si tendra que ver con las clases que tiene bootstrap predeterminadas pero antes de agregar el JS todo funcionaba bien.

***este es el código del JS***

```
var button = document.getElementById('hamburger-menu'),
span = button.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

button.onclick =  function() {
span.classList.toggle('hamburger-menu-button-close');
};

$('#hamburger-menu').on('click', toggleOnClass);

function toggleOnClass(event) {
var toggleElementId = '#' + $(this).data('toggle'),
element = $(toggleElementId);

element.toggleClass('on');

  }

// close hamburger menu after click a
$( '.menuEfecto li a' ).on("click", function(){
$('#hamburger-menu').click();
});
```

*** codigo html del menu ***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" id="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button id="hamburger-menu" data-toggle="ham-navigation" class=" hamburger-menu-button navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#menuLateral">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><span class="hamburger-menu-button-open"></span>
            <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" id="menuLateral" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="offcanvas-header" data-bs-theme="dark">
            <button class="btn-close equis" type="button" aria-label="Close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-between px-0" id="menu">
            <ul class="menuEfecto navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menuHome" aria-current="page" href="#inicio">Inicio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menuNosotros" href="#acerca">Acerca</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menuProyectos" href="#pestanas">Proyectos</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menuContacto" href="#contacto">Contácto</a>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Tu código no es reproducible, debes agregar un [MCVE] donde se aprecie claramente el problema que describes.

Comment: 1. Tu código no es JS puro, es jQuery. 2. Si es Bootstrap, ¿qué versión es? De hecho, desde la versión 5 ya no utiliza jQuery para las animaciones. 3. Por último, como te han indicado, muestra un [repro] del problema en cuestión.